# Responsive UI (scale and repos elements)

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, responsive

I'm trying to design a responsive UI for my game.
I'd like that UI elements are scaled when screen resolution is below a certain threshold and repositioned otherwise.

Let's see it in an example.
I assume that the resolution of 1600 x 900 is the one below which UI elements must be scaled down keeping their aspect ratio.
In the following images, you can see the size that the red and the green panels should take at different resolutions (1600 x 900 in the former, 1280 x 720 in the latter).
[image: 900p]

On the contrary, when the screen resolution is greater than 1600 x 900 the panels should be simply reposed, without being scaled.
You can see an example, for a resolution of 1920 x 1080, in the following image.
[image: 1080p]

I've been able to realize both logics, but not at the same time.
I've followed [this article](http://hilllo.com/limit-max-width-of-a-layout-component-in-unity/) for repos logic (key point is to have a max size for panels) and Unity UI system tutorial for the scaling logic.

Answer (score 0):

**You could have 2 sets of prefab, one for each version and then swap them as needed depending on resolution.**

This could be implemented by always having both canvases on the screen but only having the one shown that is supposed to be active in the current screen resolution.

Comment: I'd like to avoid the double prefabs solution because it would means that I'd have to replicate UI status (eg which is the focused button) on both prefabs.